# Azure Logic App. Write to different blob containers, based on email attachment name

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-logic-apps

I am in the process of creating an Azure Logic App.

My requirements are as follow:

1. Check Office365 mailbox every 5 minutes for new mail.
2. Trigger when new email with attachment is detected.
3. Copy that attachment (.xls file) and place in respective blob folder, based on name of attachment.

I have the following so far. The mail trigger with attachment is set, and is set to check every 5 minutes.

[image]

How can I, based on the name of the attachment, write to different blob folders?

Comment: Do you want the blob folder the same name with attachment name, or just want to send attachment to several blob folder with some condition?

Comment: @JoeyCai The folders already exist, I just need to, based on the name of the attachment, add it to a certain folder.

Comment: What your criteria for the classification about the attachment name?

Comment: If the file name contains X, send it to FolderExampleName1, if file name contains Y, send it to FolderExample2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the file name contains X, send it to FolderExampleName1, if file name contains Y, send it to FolderExample2.

According to your description, I think you could use a `condition` to achieve what you want.

When your Attachment Name contains "hello", it will go to `/data/f1` folder, otherwise it will go to `/data/f2` folder. You could refer to the snapshot as below:
[image]

Also, if you have two more folders, you could `Add a parallel branch` under the MailBox trigger.
[image]

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks